# Can't convert a HTTP response to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, django, fetch

I'm fetching my own API,

```
fetch('/guidebook/api/peak-data/')
          .then(response => response.json()) 
          .then(response => JSON.stringify((response))) 
          .then(data => {
            console.log('Raw JSON data:', data);
            console.log('Type of data:', typeof data);
            console.log('Type of features:', typeof data.features);
        
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error:', error);
          });
```

The data come from this function, it's published in api/peak-data

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.returnPage),
        path('api/peak-data/', views.get_peak_data, name='peak_data'),
]
```

```
def get_peak_data(request):
    peaks = Peak.objects.all()
    peak_data = serialize('geojson', peaks, geometry_field='peak_coordinates')
    return JsonResponse(peak_data, safe=False, content_type='application/json')
```

Here is the associated django model :

```
class Peak(models.Model):
    peak_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    peak_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    peak_coordinates = postgismodel.PointField(geography=True, default=Point(0, 0), blank=True, null = True)
    peak_elevation = models.IntegerField()
```

I Convert it to JSON, and for some reason, I obtain a string

```
Type of data: string 
Type of features: undefined 
No features found in the JSON data.
```

I'm struggling to understand why. In particular, I'd like to isolate the coordinates attributes using the Json, but since I do not have one, I can't

Answer (score 1):

In this step you turn your response body into a javascript object:

```
      .then(response => response.json())
```

In this step you do the opposite again, so you're back to a JSON string.

```
      .then(response => JSON.stringify((response)))
```

A string will not have a `.features` property, so `data.features` makes no sense because `data` is a string.

If you remove this line it makes more sense:

```
      .then(response => JSON.stringify((response)))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I did removed the line as suggested, however, I'm still obtaining a string for the type of data

Comment: @LorteauErwan what are you getting for the raw data?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to replace

```
return JsonResponse(peak_data, safe=False, content_type='application/json')
```

By a standart HTTP response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).